# ApplicationContext fails to Autowire in unit Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm writing a test for my @Configuration class and it crashes when autowiring the ApplicationContext. There is only one Config class in the package. The beans work in a normal execution, oddly.

Here's the basis of the test.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AWSConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {""})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "sun.*", "javax.net.ssl.*"})
@PrepareForTest({AWSConfig.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mycompany..."})
public class AppConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
```

This fails with being unable to load the context, the root cause being a class not found.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.AWSConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e9f0fdf
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:178)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:284)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mycompany.*"})` instead of `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mycompany..."})`

Or

simply use `@ComponentScan("com.mycompany.*")`

Comment: This didn't change the error, but thanks for the heads up!